# An always increasing function

Tags: functions, special-functions

Suppose I wanted a function $f(x)$ such that the following properties are had.

$f(x)$ maps $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

$f(a)>f(b)$ if $a>b$.

The function may or may not be continuous, but it doesn't have singularities.

Is there a special name for this type of function and does it have any special properties?  (properties for all functions that meet the requirements.)

Comment: It is called strictly increasing, and one thing about strictly increasing functions on $\mathbb{R}$ is that they are differentiable everywhere except a set of measure zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strictly monotone increasing. Any such function is continuous almost everywhere. But what do you mean by singularities? It could have jump discontinuities, in fact, it could have infinitely many. As pointed out by Merlinsbeard, it is in fact almost everywhere differentiable (which is even stronger)

Comment: Does that mean I can differentiate it even though it isn't continuous everywhere?

Comment: @simpleart you can diffrentiate at all continuous points.  piece wise functions is the easiest way.

Comment: @shaihorowitz What if was continuous nowhere?

Comment: @simpleart no such functions exist. check out https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function specifically f can only have jump discontinuities;
f can only have countably many discontinuities in its domain.

Comment: @shaihorowitz The link says that my function has limits from the left and right at every point in the domain, which is possibly untrue, because can't I have discontinuities in such a way that you can't take limits?

Comment: @merlinsbeard  Monotonic_function analysis is not by strong suit so someone should take over discussing of details in chat or possibly ask it as a question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40086/discussion-between-simple-art-and-shai-horowitz).

Comment: @simpleart if it only has countable discontinuities then it doesn't have an interval where it's discontinuous

Comment: @shaihorowitz: it is not true that a strictly increasing function is differentiable at all continuous points. E.g., if $f(x) = 3x$ when $x < 0$ and $f(x) = 2x$ when $x \ge 0$, then $f$ is continuous but not differentiable at $0$.